# Div border in this form: blank gaps in the corners

Tags: html, css, border

How to accomplish this div border using css:
[image]

I tried using dashed border but leads to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/23qGr/

```
div {width: 20px; 
height: 20px; border: 6px #6a817d dashed; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/anyway-to-limit-border-length I think you will have to use 4 other `div`s or pseudo-elements for the border.

Comment: Have you thought about making something in CorelDraw/Illustrator/any other vector-based software and then simply uploading as SVG? It is really easy. A CSS solution is possible, but a bit complicated.

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev The border will be a subject of alternate displays, so css will the do the trick, i'll check with SVG

Answer (score 9):

You could use pseudo element and transparent/black borders : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/23qGr/1/)**

```
div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding:6px;
    position:relative;
}
div:before , div:after {
    content:'';
    border:6px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
}
div:before {
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-top-color:black;
    border-bottom-color:black;
}
div:after {
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-right-color:black;
    border-left-color:black;
}
```

If you increse border-width, it looks better : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23qGr/2/)

Comment: +1 thanks, as I commented above the borders are to be displayed dynamiclay, the point is to make a "visual-graphic" counter.