# Borders only between elements

Tags: css, border

I need to know how to make a borders between my items like the following image:

[image]

I tried making it using `border-right` and -left but the last item shouldn't have a `border-right`.

My CSS:

```
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
```

How can I apply `border-right` to all but the last element on the row?

Comment: there tutorials should be helpful

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your `style.css`, turn off `border-right` every 4th books. (this only works on the desktop version of the site.)

```
.nspArt:nth-child(4n) .gkResponsive img.nspImage {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to control the height of the borders !! cuz i searched alot but i didn't find anything except sizing the container is this true :D !

Comment: you can play margin and padding of the parents. If you want only part of the border (for instance, only 50% of the right border), you have to create another div (parent position relative, new div position absolute) to do the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/anyway-to-limit-border-length

Answer (score 22):

There is a better way to do it that works in older browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/mxV92/.

You simply apply a border on the left for every item that immediately follows another item:

```
ul > li + li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Thats good solution too but the issue in my code that all the <li> followed with another <li> except the last one of course, and they are splitted every each 4 li.

Comment: In that case, you just clear every 5th one on the left and for these 5th ones you remove the border, margin, and padding on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/dp5MH/.

Comment: So i have to use the 'nth' property! is it compatible with older browsers !

Comment: In older browsers, you can add more markup by, for example, designating each list item that starts a row with a `class = "first"`: http://jsfiddle.net/582KV/.  Or, mark each row using HTML.  Or, use a polyfill: http://html5polyfill.com/.

Comment: mmm really thanx for your support great help :) i will try it :)

Answer (score 11):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to have borders on the right of all the items, **except** the last item.

You can use the 'last-child' selector for that. For example, if your objects were in a 'div' with the class 'foo', your CSS might look like:

```
div.foo {
   border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
   border-color: #000;
   border-style: solid;
}

div.foo:last-child { border-width: 1px 0 0 0; }
```

This says that divs of class 'foo' should have solid black borders, with a width of 1px on top and right ('border-width' is followed by widths in the order top, right, bottom, left), **except** on the last item, where the width is '1px' only on the top.

':last-child' should be supported by most modern browsers.

Comment: if you inspect the page, the author uses `float`, and the `last-child` is not the book on the far right side.

Comment: That can be fixed by adding containers for each row.

Comment: thanx alot for your help & @huocp fixed it correctly thanx to him too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```css
.books-collection {
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.books-collection .book:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```