# Button with partial border on top and bottom

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi all,
I would like to insert a `<button>` in my code that has a gap in `border-top` and `border-bottom`. I have seen some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length) where it is possible to remove a part with it, but it's not exactly what I am looking for. Do you have an idea on how to get something like the above mentioned picture?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

**EDIT:**

I add more information: the best is that the background of the button is transparent and that the `border-size` is customisable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use pseudo elements

```css
.brd {  
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.brd:before,
.brd:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
}
.brd:before {
  border-right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.brd:after {
  border-left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="brd">Title</span>

<button class="brd">Title</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to use gradient as `border-image`. Look at the snippet below

```css
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;

  border: 3px solid transparent;

  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #aaa 10%, #fff 10%, #fff 90%, #aaa 90%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #aaa 10%, #fff 10%, #fff 90%, #aaa 90%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #aaa 10%, #fff 10%, #fff 90%, #aaa 90%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >TITLE HERE</div>
```

If you want the top and bottom border parts to be exactly X pixels, you can change the percents with pixels like this:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #aaa 20px, #fff 20px, #fff calc(100% - 20px), #aaa calc(100% - 20px));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be using a custom made image as the background of your button, tho it wouldn't scale well on different screen sizes.

Another idea would be to have a div underneath with a normal border, and then your smaller button on top of it, with the same height and a white border, so as to hide the top and bottom part.

Comment: I thought about using an `svg` format, but it would be better to have it in pure css

Comment: @LGSon 's answer is the best one, then. Didn't know you could use pseudo-elements that way. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JSFiddle for you: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/uzvzx1cm/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="back-with-border">
  <div class="front-no-border">
    Title Here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.back-with-border{
  border:1px solid gray;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
}

.front-no-border{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 border:0px;
 background-color:white;
 position: absolute;
 width:110px;
 height:110px;
 top:-1px;
 left:45px
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That's a good solution, but it would be nice to have one with a transparent background

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this [JSFiddle][1], hope this will solve your problem 



    body {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .parent {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
    }

    .child {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 103px;
      top: -1px;
      left: 25px
    }
     <div class="parent">
       <div class="child">
         Write your text here
       </div>
     </div>




  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/anshul24mehta/eocst0uv/3/
```