# Create corner border in CSS

Tags: html, css, border

How can I create the "blue" and "orange" corners in CSS, like in this image:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? Explain in detail or you can google it yourself

Comment: There's a solution here you can base it on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes like this:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    border-top: 3px solid blue;
    border-right: 3px solid blue;
}
span:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    border-left: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Comment: It's work, Thank's a lot

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use 'before' and 'after' elements only one HTML tag is required ie. the outermost div in this case and call up the before and after elements on this element. Extra tags add up on the renderer load.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

div:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

div:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
div{
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    div.outer{
          height:150px;
          width:150px;
          position:relative;
          background:#fff;
          padding:2px;
        }
       div.inner {
                border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
                 height:100%;
          width:100%;
        }
        div.outer:before{
          content:"";
          background:#F87200;
          width:25px;
          height:25px;
          position:absolute;
          bottom:-5px;
          left:-5px;
          display:block;
          z-index: -1;
        }
        div.outer:after{
          content:"";
          background:#0092D4;
          width:25px;
          height:25px;
          position:absolute;
          top:-5px;
          right:-5px;
          display:block;
          z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
```