# Underline exactly 50% of my text

Tags: html, css

I wanted to underline my title only 50%. Here is my code, tried with `border-bottom`.

```css
h1{
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to limit border length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length)

Comment: 50% of what? Of title width? Of page width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `:before` element to make pseudo element.
Basically we make a 50% width, 5px height element and place it via position:absolute at the bottom:

```css
h1{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /* Header are 100% width by their default block behaviour */
}
h1:before{
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1>I am a pretty header</h1>
```

---

Comment: Nope. You are missing `content: ""` and `absolute` is spelt wrong.

Comment: And now it does :) was figuring out why it didnt work haha, missed the typo. That made things weird

Comment: why is h1:before not applying background for whole "divs" height and why it is applying only on bottom? I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Great, thats what we're going for. @AmelSalibasic: I've added more explanation how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `::after` pseudo element for this though you would have to make the `h1` `inline-block` to stop it spanning the full width of the parent.

Using `::after` rather than `::before` means that you don't have to use any `absolute` positioning.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

You could also centre the border using `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

Or to the right...

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Now for the bonus, add a middle (`left:50%, transform:translateX(-50%)`). I do suggest to add them in one example and work via classes as that makes a cleaner answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want it to underline 50% of the text or 50% of the width?

To underline 50% of the total width, simply set the element's width to 50%:

```css
h1{
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

To make it underline 50% of the TEXT you'll have to use a bit tricker CSS. You have to create an element inside the title element and set it to an inline block so it only is as width as the text itself. Then create the border using the other element that is 50% the size of the text element (also inline-block). The easiest way to do that is to use a div inside the h1.

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  TITLE
  <div class="line"></div>
</h1>
```

That's starting to look like it right. But the extra div element is kinda messy.

If you prefer to achieve this without the extra div you can automatically generate the element using the css :[after](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) selector as in the example below:

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1>TITLE
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```css
h1{
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
}
h1:after{
  content:"";
   position:absolute;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   width:75px;
   bottom:-5px;
   left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```html
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
</style>

<div>
   <h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
```