# How defining output length & adding 2 background to button in CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I've been working on my first [website](https://shir0206.github.io/NyquistOptics-Web/) and run out with some questions I couldn't find any solution online. Hopefully someone could guide me what are the keywords I should lookup.

1) How can I define the length of the border of the `output` (without wrapping it with `div`)? I would like to set a constant width of the `output` value (that would be empty if there is no value), but I can't seem to find how to do so. In CSS, border-bottom-width actually set the height.

```
output {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 3em 0% 3em 0%;
    color: aquamarine;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}
```

2) How can I set to a floating `button` a `gradient` in the back background and an `image` in the front? For some reason, it seems that I can use only one of them.

```
<button onclick="calc(this)" class="calc" src="/img/calculator.svg"></button>
```

.

```
.calc {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2)  url('/img/calculator.svg'); //the picture isn't shown
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    outline: none;
    border: #17375e;
}
```

Comment: For background please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds, it's comma separated. As far as the border is concerned, border width only defines how thick the border is. You cannot set a length to borders, you would have to add another element to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length

Comment: @Huangism Thanks! about the 2 backgrounds - for some reason the picture isn't shown, even when i set only a picture - "background-image: url(/img/calculator.svg);"
The picture exists and there are no typos. What should I check in order to fix it?

Comment: Your url is wrong, you using `/img` which is absolute path and it is not the correct path. If you remove the `/` it will show. Might want to move the image as the first background so you will actually see it

Comment: Thanks!
One more last issue that maybe you could help - each line contains: image, label & input. Since the height of the image is bigger, how can I center-align vertically the label&input according to the image heigt?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, I suggest you google it. there are lots of stackoverflow questions on vertical centering