# HTML Custom Frame

Tags: html, css, html-email

Hi everyone I'm looking to achieve the following for an email template.

[image]

Can anyone help with this. I been trying with border radius but doesn't seems to work.

Appreciate the help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show youe code.Make a simple example: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/. Or  Minimal - reproducible example:https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to limit border length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length) - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length#42157360) which has the exact result you need

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box::before{
  content: '';
  width:50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.box::after{
  content: '';
  width:50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
Some Text Here<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your contributions are welcome on Stack Overflow, however when a question already has an answer like this one has, then the correct action is to flag it as a duplicate, so that the site doesn't get cluttered with redundant questions that have already been answered :) Please see [Answer well-asked questions in "How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you have a new answer to this problem, you can always add it to the original question that the duplicates point to.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered here : [Any way to limit border length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length)

But I used border-width, and with `::before` and `::after`

```css
.mainwrapper{
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
}
.mainwrapper:before,.mainwrapper:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: #111;
  border-style: solid;
  content: ' ';
}
.mainwrapper:before{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.mainwrapper:after{
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwrapper">
    <p>something text here</p>
    <p>something text here</p>
    <p>something text here</p>
    <p>something text here</p>
    <p>something text here</p>
    <p>something text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your contributions are welcome on Stack Overflow, however when a question already has an answer like this one has, then the correct action is to flag it as a duplicate, so that the site doesn't get cluttered with redundant questions that have already been answered :) Please see [Answer well-asked questions in "How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you have a new answer to this problem, you can always add it to the original question that the duplicates point to.