# How to position brackets and symbols relative to a form input grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

So I'm fairly new to HTML and JS and i wanted to add some brackets and a equal sign around this grid of input forms in order to make it look more like a system of matrices. Idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wez8z.jpg
I've tried positioning them on the CSS sheet with position absolute for each bracket but then if I change the matrix's size or resize the browser's window, it doesn't work. How would i do this in the CSS or in the HTML/Javascript file so the brackets rescale for bigger sizes and stay in the correct spot?

```css
span {
  font-family: 'Latin Modern Math';
  position: absolute;
  top: 228px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  font-size: 56px;
}

.a1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
}

.a2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 618px;
}

.x1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 679px;
}

.x2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 780px;
}

.igual {
  position: absolute;
  left: 820px;
  top: 220px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  font-size: 58px;
}

.b1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 882px;
}

.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 982px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/linear" method="post">
  <div class="col-auto my-1">
    <select style="margin: 15px 0px 20px;" id="dim_select" name="dim_select" class="custom-select largura" onchange="change()">
      <option disabled selected>Dimension</option>
      {% for i in range(3, 8) %}
      <option>{{ i }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- MATRIZ A GERADA POR JS -->

  <div id="matrizAcontainer">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      grid(3, 3);
    });

    function change() {
      var select = document.getElementById("dim_select");
      var index = select.selectedIndex
      var n = parseInt(select.value);
      grid(n, n);

    };

    function grid(rows, cols) {
      var table = '<span class="a1">[</span>';
      table += "<table>";

      var size = ((screen.availWidth / 2.45) / rows) + "px";

      for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        table += '<tr class="spacing-50">';
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          table += '<td>' + '<input class="matrizA" name="A' + (i + 1) + (j + 1) + '" placeholder="a' + (i + 1) + (j + 1) + '"/>' + '</td>';
        }
        if (i == 0) {
          table += '<span class="a2">]</span>';
          table += '<span class="x1">[</span>';
          table += '<span class="x2">]</span>';
          table += '<div class="igual">=</div>';
          table += '<span class="b1">[</span>';
        }
        table += '<td><input class="matrizX" placeholder="x' + (i + 1) + '" disabled/></td>';
        table += '<td><input class="matrizB" name="B' + (i + 1) + '" placeholder="b' + (i + 1) + '"/></td>';
        table += "</tr>";
      }
      table += "</table>";
      table += '<span class="b2">]</span>';

      $("#matrizAcontainer").empty();
      $("#matrizAcontainer").append(table);
      $("tr").css("height", 32 + "px");
      $("input").css("width", size);
      $(".matrizX").css("text-align", "center");
      $(".matrizX").css("margin-left", 80 + "px").css("width", 80 + "px");
      $(".matrizX").css("background", "#dedddf");
      $(".matrizB").css("margin-left", 120 + "px").css("width", 80 + "px");
      var bracket = (32 * (rows + 1));
      $("span").css("transform", "scaleY(" + (bracket / 50) + ")");
    }
  </script>

  <button style="margin: 20px 0px 20px; width: auto;" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" type="submit"><b>Solve</b></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length)

```css
body{
  display: flex;
}
#mainDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}

#borderLeft {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#borderRight {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left : 4px;
}
#mainDivRight {
  height: 100px;
  width: 8px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="borderLeft"></div>
</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</p>
<div id="mainDivRight">
  <div id="borderRight"></div>
</div>
```

Different idea:
Size the width and height as you wish, or set it to auto.
Use an svg image for the background.

```css
div{
  width:200px;
  height:100px; 
 background: lightblue url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mathematics-line-3/48/113-512.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
<div id="brackets">
</div>
```