# How to change the width of a CSS border independently from it's parent?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to apply a custom border on a `div`. I'd like that border to have a length/width (unsure on how I should name this) that's independent from the `div` width.

I know a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length) but isn't there a new solution that doesn't rely on adding some extra HTML ?

[image]

```css
#foo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    border-top: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: The link in your question makes sense to me, aren't the answers helping you? ::after pseudo-element is some CSS, not extra HTML

Comment: Aren't pseudo-element "some extra HTML" ? It's just that I'm not really comfortable with the idea adding an extra HTML element to do styling. But yeah that method indeed work, I would just like to checkout if there is any new updated way to achieve this.

Comment: They're note extra HTML. The browser displays it on the developper tab "Elements" to interract with them but they're not.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I'm more comfortable with using them then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using ::before and ::after

```css
#foo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#foo::before {
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  margin-left: calc((100px - 80px)/2);
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `calc`! It a bit closer to the kind of dynamism I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick :)

Inspired by one of the non-accepted answers on the link you posted

```css
#foo {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#foo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: blue; 

    width: 80%; 
    left: 10%;

    height: 10px;
    top: -10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```